# How to change Information on an existing web page

Tags: html, web-deployment

Right now i am building out my first web page for a friend. She told me that she would like to be able to change infos and files like for example pictures or also the availabilty of her house in a calendar.
So my question is once the website is online how would i change things like that.
PS: Sorry for asking such a question on this platform since it seems most of the questions are purely reagrding coding, but I am new to the development world and I couldn't really find a good answer to that through google.

Comment: You are looking for a [Simple CMS](https://www.google.com/search?q=simple+cms+site%3Astackoverflow.com) and as such is not on topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Hello gundelgurke: As for me, the context is missing on your question. What was used to create the Website (from scratch, any CMS or?). Is the website self-hosted? Do you have access to the files (source) of the Website?